# What would be the right Cultural Name of People that Identify being from a Federation

Tags: society, culture, names

In my sci-fi book there is a faction that is a Federation (so original right). So a bunch of Colonial Sectors joined together under a federal government to fight against a much more powerful faction. Hundreds of years have passed wars won and lost, planets taken and retaken, and the people on both sides becoming ever bitter about the other. The federal government knowing that a divided was present used it for its own gains. The government made it that your Cultural Identity wasn't based on your race or creed (all were very watered down anyway) but based on the government you were born under. So how would people identify as being one. I know that it would be a broad sweep like John Doe is a Federation citizen, But I'm stuck on name they would use abbreviations and all. like would outsiders call them Federals, Feds, and Federations list goes on. The idea comes from the way the cold war went about putting everybody under one group like commies and capitalist, just that each side embraced the name.

**The Question: What would be the right Cultural Name of People that Identify being from a Federation**

Comment: Tbh the ones you've suggested all sound like perfectly adequate fits for the title. "Federation Citizen". If you're instead looking for a shortened version then "Feddie" sounds like something people would use.

Comment: I apologize, but this quesiton is going to get closed.  [As you can see from a search of the site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+what+name) virtually all questions like this are closed.  That's because the answer is by definition either too story-based or primarily opinion-based.  Said another way, you're not asking us to help build the consistent rules of a fictional world, you're asking us to help generate ideas for an aesthetic.

Comment: @JBH i know where your coming from but this far from do my work for me type of stuff. "too story-based or primarily opinion-based" how so? i get it if i asked to name say the Neet-Empire because there's no right answer, but I'm asking about a real government type, under a real set of names that could be used like commies and capitalist. i just want to know if there is a right way of naming the people or is it making it up as you go along

Comment: Worldbuilding is about the consistent use of rules that describe a fictional world in which many stories can be told.  Names are good for a limited number of stories and possibly only one.  That's what too story-based means.  Further, any name is as good as another, and while you can narrow the number of names by providing more and more limitations on what name *could* be the best name, in the end, you're not picking one based on most-suitable-for-the-reasons-I've-given, but the one you simply like the best.  That's off-topic for all Stack Exchange sites. (\*continued\*)

Comment: Unless there is some sort of history there, then the Federation's citizens will be known as you have suggested. If there is history, of any sort, usually of a derogatory nature, then that will be the source of the common title, e.g., communists are known as Reds due the red flags signifying union work stoppages, the French are called "frogs" because they allegedly consider frog legs a delicacy, and so on...

Comment: If you read through the fairly long list of closed "what name should I use for X?" questions, you'll discover these same two patterns over and over.  Names are just the window dressing of your story.  They are not a "rule" governing the operation of your world.  And anytime you try to make one a "rule," it instantly becomes too story-based because that can only true due to the circumstances of your story, not the manifestation of your world.  To make a point, call your citizens "fred," it's as good a name as any (other than you might not like it).

Comment: Ask in Stack English language and usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of [federal states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_system_of_government#Federal) on this planet to take examples from.

Being german, I'll just take my home country as an example:
Germans just call themselves germans or sometimes by their place of origin, e.g. germans from the state of Bavaria occasionally call themselves bavarians and it's an endless source of joy for people outside berlin when people from [Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin) use the german term [berliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_(doughnut)) for themselves. Special to germany is also the east/west division with `wessi` (west german) and `ossi` (east german).

There is also the term `Bundesbürger`, literally translated as `Federal Citizen`, which I have never heard anyone use outside of law, documentaries and news reports about laws.

As for your story, I'd go either with the name of the federation or the planet.
`Solarian Federation` => `Solarians`
`Citizen from the planet Foobar in the united federation of planets` => `Foobarians`